# How are the feasts of Purim and Hanukkah justified in light of Devarim 4:2 and 13:1?

Tags: derabanan, chagim-holidays, vaeschanan, parashat-reeh, bal-tosif-no-adding

According to Devarim 4:2 (and 13:1), there are to be no additions to the Torah (**'Do not add to what I command you and do not subtract from it, but keep the commands of the Lord your God that I give you . . . All this word which I command you, that shall you observe to do; you shall not add thereto, nor diminish from it**')  In light of that, how are the feasts of Purim and Hanukkah, two additional feasts, justified? Even further, Shemini Azeret and Simchat Torah?

Comment: Shemini Atzeret is in the Torah https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.36?lang=bi

Comment: A large part of this question duplicates the linked-to question. If you want to edit this question removing that part, it can be reopened.

Comment: @msh210 I give you permission to edit it suitably.

Comment: No can do: I don't know what part of the question is still important to you after you've read that other page.

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/246/why-still-keep-two-days-of-yom-tov-outside-of-israel

Comment: Also relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/halachic-restrictions-not-in-the-torah-and-shall-not-add https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/why-arent-purim-and-channuka-considered-a-violation-of-%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%90-%D7%AA%D6%B9%D7%A1%D6%B4%D7%A4%D7%95%D6%BC?noredirect=1&lq=1